# iOS - Crash when gesture detected logged by Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, stack-trace, crashlytics

I set gesture recognizer for my tableView:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressDetected:")
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

and when I am trying it, it works fine. I've sent app to beta test and I have several times crash with this log:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  IamDJ                          4295807340 specialized ProjectDetailViewController.longPressDetected(AnyObject) -> () (ProjectDetailViewController.swift)
1  IamDJ                          4295765652 @objc ProjectDetailViewController.longPressDetected(AnyObject) -> () (ProjectDetailViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          6613447472 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 164
3  UIKit                          6609423196 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 172
4  UIKit                          6607906908 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 784
5  UIKit                          6613452556 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke898 + 72
6  UIKit                          6607640760 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 372
7  UIKit                          6607627836 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2404
8  UIKit                          6607898316 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1132
9  UIKit                          6607895752 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 764
10 UIKit                          6607701156 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
11 UIKit                          6607693676 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5528
12 CoreFoundation                 6517671236 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
13 CoreFoundation                 6517669848 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
14 CoreFoundation                 6517660888 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
15 CoreFoundation                 6516804768 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
16 GraphicsServices               6703693960 GSEventRunModal + 180
17 UIKit                          6608130044 UIApplicationMain + 204
18 IamDJ                          4296201300 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
19 libdyld.dylib                  6874491064 start + 4
```

How can I find where is the problem? What's wrong with that `longPressDetected` method? I've tried this method for last 2 hours and nothing crashed. I am using same device and same iOS version (iPhone 6, iOS 9.1). There is 5% free RAM in one of the logs. Could it be problem with releasing memory? Thanks for any help

Comment: `_UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions` it could be the target does not exist anymore